# How can I pass a list of icons to "addItems" for QComboBox

Tags: python, pyqt

In PyQt you can give an `icon` & `string` as argument in `QComboBox.addItem()`
I'm trying to do something similar with `QComboBox.addItems()`. I want to give a list of icons, and list of strings as arguments.

```py
myIcons = [QtGui.QPixmap(), QtGui.QPixmap(), QtGui.QPixmap()]
myStrings = ['Project1', 'Project2', 'Project3']

myComboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
myComboBox.addItems(myIcons, myStrings)
```

I'm guessing I will have to subclass `QComboBox()` and change the `addItems()` method to be like `addItem()` except with a list. I just don't know how to view the source code for those methods to be able to change them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the `addItems` method does not support passing icons, you can do what you want in a loop

```
for icon, string in zip(myIcons, myStrings):
    myComboBox.addItem(icon, string)
```